# How would I fix material icons always showing on top? (HTML)

Tags: html, google-material-icons

I have a webpage with a loading menu that greys out the background while the loading menu is shown. The menu is last in the document as to be on-top of the rest of the page. However, when using [Google's Material Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material+Icons), the icon appears above the loading menu.

My guess would be that the icons load last, and as such are infront of static parts of the webpage.

I would expect and prefer the icon to be behind the loading menu. How could I achieve this?

In addition, I use bootstrap. I do not believe that my issue resides with bootstrap, however it may be crucial to understanding the code snippits.

Snippit of buttons: (*I included more than neccesary incase my issue resides outside the icons*)

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">Link:</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="studentLink" value="<?=studentLink?>" readonly>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-light h-100" onclick="copyLinkToClipboard()">
      <span class="material-icons"style="font-size: 1em">
        content_copy
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Snippit of Loading Menu:

```html
<!-- Loading Alert -->
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="position: absolute; top:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; visibility: visible" id="loadingAlert">
  <div class="bg-light opacity-75" style="position: absolute; top:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%"> </div>
  <div class="shadow col-6 card bg-info text-white">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="me-2 spinner-border align-self-center"></div>
        <div class="vr"></div>
        <h3 class="mx-2 align-self-end">Loading:</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <h1>Creating Session</h1>
      <h3>Please wait</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Think you need to use z-index: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Kip for the answer.

Add the css style 'z-index' to the loading element.

Example (Based upon my code snippit):

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="position: absolute; top:0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; visibility: visible; z-index: 1000" id="loadingAlert">
...
</div>
```

Note the section style="z-index: 1000".

This feels like a very clunky solution, as why would you need to update the z-index, but here the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

```
  .css-8je8zh-MuiTouchRipple-root,.css-78trlr-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root{
    position:static !important ;
}
```

if you're using 
Simply add this into your style.css and boom